# Input while using Graphics.h

Tags: c++, bgi

I am making a login page for a game , That uses outextxy() for output;

So I would like to have the input at a specific desired location ( at specific coordinates )
[using cin doesn't help  it stills input from the top of the program ],

Is there any inbuilt function for this ??

I have even tried using gotoxy() ..but didn't work ,

```
gotoxy(320,15);
cin>>a;
```

It will be really helpful if u can explain or give a link to explain( if it requires good knowledge , cause i am still a beginner )

Comment: What library are you using? `outextxy` isn't part of the C++ standard.

Comment: header file - graphics.h
i dont know surely of the library ,,.. but i think it is WINBGIM .. its old version of TC ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i figured it out... it was stupidity on my part .. referred the help file and came to know that gotoxy has some maximum arguments  ( but I still don't understand  the value of arguements )

Courtesy : Lundin

Comment: That isn't true. Back in the days when people used gotoxy, it worked with 80, 25, which was the standard width of the old DOS screen.

Comment: so how can i know what will be the maximum arguments ...?

Comment: gotoxy moves the cursor to the given position in the current text window. If the coordinates are in any way invalid the call to gotoxy is ignored. An example of this is a call to gotoxy(40,30) when (35,25) is the bottom right position in the window. Neither argument to gotoxy can be zero

Comment: @Lundin yeah its working for 80 , 25 ,,.... but still it isnt reaching the bottom of the screen !

Comment: I truly don't remember how to do these things, I haven't used them during the past 15 years :)  80, 25 was the standard DOS screen however. If you want to take user input in BGI and make it look nice, I don't think you should use gotoxy, but rather use outtextxy to print something, then use getch to collect user input, then echo user input with outtextxy again. This will be rather tedious however, and all input will be in string format, meaning you may have to convert it if you want integers.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading from cin just as you are used to. But it is you that should take care to display what is displayed. C++ won't do that for you. For instance if you are entering a string after entering a character, you have to display it in the desired location. Things get even messier once you start dealing with correction in the input(i.e. pressing backspace). I have implemented several games using graphics.h myself and remember dealing with all this tweaks was hell.

My proposal is that you try to use a more advance graphics library. My personal choice is usually opengl. For it you can find a lot of helper libraries for instance wxWidgets.

Comment: Actually I remember making a text editor in BGI, which used getch() and echoed whatever the user typed in fancy VGA graphics :)  But I wouldn't recommend anyone to do that in 2012...

Comment: bound to using TC 3.0  and graphics.h /// cant help it :(

Answer (score 0):

graphics.h is part of the ancient DOS library called BGI, delivered with old Borland compilers only. Borland stopped supporting this 15 years ago. In fact Borland doesn't even make compilers any longer. And no other compiler has ever supported it. Also, Windows no longer support 16-bit DOS programs so you can't even run BGI programs on modern computers.

Don't use graphics.h.

Better alternatives are OS-dependent. In Windows you should use the [console functions API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and in Linux there is a library called [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). Though of course, this would mean that you would have to upgrade to 32 bit computer...

Comment: the biggest problem is that i am surrounded by computers containing TC 3.0 in my school... so i have to specifically take up TC 3.0 ...i know its crappy

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha I'm guessing you are from India then :) This seems to be a huge problem in the programming education there, for some reason they have decided to teach everyone old crap that nobody uses. My advise is to put minimum effort into learning TC-specific things. Instead, you should download GCC and do all programming there. If you learn about Windows or Linux libraries instead of BGI, it will actually be of some use for you in the future, if you consider a programmer career.

Comment: guessed correctly.... there are only some months left so that i pass out of my school ... then i will surely leave tC behind .. !!!